# Stackmob linker error

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, stackmob

I've started using Stackmob. I follow the instructions provided and add stackmob to my project, then turn off all of the ARC on those files added, and then I get the linker error.

"clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Anyone came across the same issue? Once I remove stackmob from the project it compiles again.

Comment: It should have more precise errors above it or in the build log.

Comment: There are a host of reasons that the linker could have failed. Add some detail. It might be that the libs aren't compatible with your hardware (written for armv7 and running on sim, for example). All guesswork without additional info.

Comment: ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/andriusste/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectPlannerPreRelease-durchbmgmfyjacbdhdlvdgcwrtwq/Build/Intermediates/ProjectPlannerPreRelease.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectPlannerPreRelease.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main-B1812428DCF39438.o and /Users/andriusste/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectPlannerPreRelease-durchbmgmfyjacbdhdlvdgcwrtwq/Build/Intermediates/ProjectPlannerPreRelease.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectPlannerPreRelease.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main-54A21E53FF3D6645.o for architecture armv7

Comment: Ok, I've created completely new project with ARC enabled, added stackmob, switched off ARC for stackmob files, then added SenTestingKit framework, because it was required. Tried to compile it and still got the same error. I remove the stackmob compiles again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the Cocoapods installation method... shouldn't get those linker errors that way.